# Android - Sqlite Query with unique and foreign key constraint

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two tables named `x` and `y`.

`x` table has two columns say `_id` and `name`.

`_id` would be primary key, `name` would be a unique constraint.

I'm not familiar with sqlite queries. Should the query be written like this?

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS x (
    _id integer primary key autoincrement, 
    name text, 
    unique(name));
```

`y` table has three  columns `_id`, `xid`, and `address`.

`_id` would be the primary key, `xid` would be a foreign key, `address` would be a unique key constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS y (
    _id integer primary key autoincrement, 
    address text, 
    xid references x(_id), 
    unique(address));
```

If I'm missing or not defining anything correctly, please, correct me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I read your question a few times, and I can't work out what you are asking. Can you perhaps be more specific about what you are asking?

Comment: Have you tried it out? Or tried looking in a sqlite language reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your commands are correct.

You could make the constraints a little bit clearer by making them column constraints instead of table constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS x (
    _id integer primary key autoincrement, 
    name text unique);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS y (
    _id integer primary key autoincrement, 
    address text unique,
    xid references x(_id));
```